# Use value from scale bar on a Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

How could I get the value from the scale bar added using:

```js
L.control.scale({position: 'bottomleft'}).addTo(map);
```

Whatever scale it shows, how to assign it to a variable in JavaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to be able to retrieve the displayed values on the Leaflet Scale Control, so that you can re-use it somewhere else (through your page JavaScript).

Most probably what you want is to convert a known pixels distance on screen to its representing geographical distance at a given latitude.

You can easily achieve this without having to use the [Scale Control](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#control-scale) at all: you can use [map conversion methods](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-conversion-methods), typically a sequence of [`containerPointToLatLng`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-containerpointtolatlng) (for 2 points separated by a known pixels distance) and [`distanceTo`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#latlng-distanceto) (between the 2 found latLng coordinates), as done in [Preciseness of leaflet measurement conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492903/preciseness-of-leaflet-measurement-conversions/40499029#40499029) and as implemented in Leaflet Scale Control's [`_update`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.3.1/src/control/Control.Scale.js#L67-L76) internal method:

```js
_update: function() {
  var map = this._map,
    y = map.getSize().y / 2;

  var maxMeters = map.distance(
    map.containerPointToLatLng([0, y]),
    map.containerPointToLatLng([this.options.maxWidth, y]));

  this._updateScales(maxMeters);
}
```

Live example:

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([48.86, 2.35], 11);

map.on('moveend', computeScale); // Also fires when zoom changes.
computeScale();

function computeScale() {
  var mapZoom = map.getZoom(),
      latitude = getContainerMidHeightLatitude(),
      distance = pixelsToMetricDistance(100).toFixed(2);
      
  alert(
      'At zoom ' + mapZoom
      + ' and latitude ' + latitude
      + ', 100 pixels represent about ' + distance + ' meters'
  );
}

function pixelsToMetricDistance(pixelsDistance) {
  var containerMidHeight = map.getSize().y / 2,
      point1 = map.containerPointToLatLng([0, containerMidHeight]),
      point2 = map.containerPointToLatLng([pixelsDistance, containerMidHeight]);

  return point1.distanceTo(point2);
}

function getContainerMidHeightLatitude() {
  var containerMidHeight = map.getSize().y / 2,
      point = map.containerPointToLatLng([0, containerMidHeight]);
  
  return point.lat.toFixed(6);
}

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 180px"></div>
```

Now if you want to take advantage of the Scale Control built-in rounding feature, you could simply "hook" into it and extract its computed values. The idea would be to customize its updating internal method, so that it calls whatever app updating function you need. We could also fire a new dedicated event on the map and listen to it:

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([48.86, 2.35], 11);

L.Control.Scale.include({
  _originalUpdateScale: L.Control.Scale.prototype._updateScale,
  // https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.3.1/src/control/Control.Scale.js#L109-L112
  _updateScale: function(scale, text, ratio) {
    this._originalUpdateScale.call(this, scale, text, ratio);
    this._map.fire('scaleupdate', {
      pixels: scale.style.width,
      distance: text
    });
  }
});

var scaleControl = L.control.scale({
  position: 'bottomleft'
});

map.on('scaleupdate', function(event) {
  alert(event.pixels + ' represent about ' + event.distance);
});

scaleControl.addTo(map);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 180px"></div>
```

Comment: The second one is what was looking for, thanks your are amazing sir

Comment: Even after parse not able to treat as float, event.distance*2 appears as NaN, how could i assign the value eveywhere in javascript

Comment: `pixels` and `distance` are _strings_ in the above provided code snippet. You can convert into float with [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) Open a new question should you need further help.

Comment: Thanks, sir for quick reply, parseFload(event.distance) gives error NaN,How can i use the number. Asking  here just because,how to use that number is also a question asked on top

Comment: wow that's an amazing answer i'm impressed, thanks a lot!